# How to Destroy multiple gameObject at runtime?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In unity3D I am creating and destroying capsule dynamically at run-time. I used **space** to create capsule and **C** for destroying.

I want create multiple object and destroy multiple object at time. When I pressed **Space** multiple times object is creating multiple time it fine.

But the problem is when I pressed **C** multiple times **only one** object is destroying. How I can achieve destroying multiple object? One by one.

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class DynamicCreate : MonoBehaviour 
 {     
     public GameObject caps;

     // Update is called once per frame
     void Update () 
     {
          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
          {
               createObject();
          }

          if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.C))
          {
               destroyObject();
          }
     }

     private void createObject()
     {
          caps = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
     }

     public void destroyObject()
     {
          Destroy(caps);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would like to add more to bolkay answer. If you want to add and remove one by one best datastructure to use is a queue.

```
Queue<GameObject> Capsules;
void Start()
{
    Capsules = new Queue<GameObject>();
}

private void createObject()
{
    GameObject caps = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
    Capsules.Enqueue(caps);
}

public void destroyObject()
{
    if(Capsules.Count > 0)
        Destroy(Capsules.Dequeue());   
}
```

[Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) data structure will give a first in first out. So it will give out first gameobject which you added to the queue at runtime and you wont need a variable to manage the index as in the state of List.

---

Note: This solution is still very basic but I would recommend you to use object pooling instead of creating and destroying objects at runtime as creating and destorying objects is quite intensive at runtime. So you should unless abosolutely necessary avoid creating and deleting.

```
Queue<GameObject> pooledObjects;
Queue<GameObject> Capsules;
void Start()
{
    pooledObjects = new Queue<GameObject>();

    Capsules = new Queue<GameObject>();
}

private void createObject()
{
    if(pooledObjects.Count > 0)
    {
        GameObject fetchedObject = pooledObjects.Dequeue();
        fetchedObject.SetActive(true);
        //Do translations,scaling or other stuff on this reference

        //Add it back to main list of things present in scene.
        Capsules.Enqueue(fetchedObject);
    } else
    {
        //Only create objects if necessary
        GameObject caps = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
        Capsules.Enqueue(caps);
    }            
}

public void destroyObject()
{
    //here instead of destorying the object we will just disable them and keep them out if scene so we dont have to recreate them everytime
    if(Capsules.Count > 0)
    {
        GameObject fetchedObject = Capsules.Dequeue();
        fetchedObject.SetActive(false);//Turn the object off from scene
        pooledObjects.Equals(fetchedObject);
    }   
}
```

---

Here is list of supported datastructures in C# you might want to [use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/collections/) depending on your required case.

Comment: I have one more query, can we give unique ID for it

Comment: For a Unique id there are multiple ways to proceed. You can either save it in a Dictionary<int,GameObject> or have a List of Classobjects with class having following variables as id & gameobject and find the reference of it from the list by matching with the id.

Comment: in **2nd code** , if I am creating multiple objects and only disable after used. then number of disable object will be increased, if I want to reuse disable objects?

Comment: `GameObject fetchedObject = pooledObjects.Dequeue();
        fetchedObject.SetActive(true);` This part of code is reusing your disabled objects if they are present.

Comment: This is not a really good reason to use a Queue over a List that is treated like a Queue. Using a list would allow the potential of not including parts of the .NET runtime (Queue is not part of the core system. List is)

Comment: @EdMarty can you provide more details on your comment. I didn't understood what exactly you are trying to say. I know you don't want to use queue but in .net runtime I have not much idea so you might want to elaborate on the second part of the content as why anyonr should prefer list treated as queue rather than a queue itself.

Comment: After researching it a bit, I have not found proof of what I was saying; I only have memories of removing the use of Queue and Stack to help decrease app size. In any case, I know that Unity does explicitly optimize the use of Lists at runtime, but this optimization would not be particularly relevant in this circumstance.

Comment: @killer_mech Hello Sir , pls help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984168/how-to-add-fbx-human-3d-object-in-gameobject-createprimitive-in-unity-c-s

Comment: @EveryThing sorry I was away these days with some work in hand. But it seems your question is resolved.

Comment: @killer_mech , will you help in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54340261/how-to-camera-zoom-in-out-position-in-unity-using-c

Answer (score 4):

You can simply create a list of capsules.
Declare a list of capsule like under:

```
List<GameObject> Capsules;
void Start()
{
    Capsules=new List<GameObject>();
}
```

Add any created capsule to the list:

```
private void createObject()
{
    caps = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
    Capsules.Add(caps);
}
```

You can then destroy the capsules in the list:

```
public void destroyObject()
{
    foreach(GameObject capsule in Capsules)
    {
        Destroy(capsule);
    }
}
```

See if that helps.

Comment: it removing all game object at time. I want remove **one by one **, on every **C** pressed.

Comment: @EveryThing just get one element at a time in from destoryObject.

Comment: @killer_mech , will u help me in that?

Comment: @bolkay , help me in in below question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53984168/how-to-add-fbx-human-3d-object-in-gameobject-createprimitive-in-unity-c-s