# How to add .fbx (Human 3D object) in GameObject.CreatePrimitive in Unity C# code?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

Previously I asked [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53879759/how-to-destroy-multiple-gameobject-at-runtime) and got proper solution for adding and destruction 3D object at run time.

By using **GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);** I can add only limited 3D object like **Cube , Capsules and other**

Now the problem is, I want add 3D human body **.fxb** object. Can I add **.fbx** object in below code?

```
Queue<GameObject> Capsules;
void Start()
{
    Capsules = new Queue<GameObject>();
}

public GameObject caps;
private void createObject()
{
    caps = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Capsule);
    Capsules.Enqueue(caps);
}
```

Comment: You should read about [prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) in this case.

Comment: @Streamline , thank you for guidance.

Comment: @Streamline , how to add **prefabs** as **gameObject** in **queue**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by using [prefabs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html). After you created your prefab in the editor
you can use it in scripts using the following code:

```
using UnityEditor;

// Loading the prefab this way only works in the editor.
GameObject myPrefab = AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath<GameObject>("Assets/Prefabs/Character.prefab");

// Use this otherwise:
// using UnityEngine;
// GameObject myPrefab = Resources.Load<GameObject>("Prefabs/Character");
// Note: The Prefabs folder has to be placed in a folder named Resources.
```

after you have your prefab loaded you can make copies using `Instantiate`.

```
GameObject character = Object.Instantiate(myPrefab);
// Set location, rotation, ...
Capsules.Enqueue(character);
```

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: **YOU CAN'T!**

`GameObject.CreatePrimitive` only creates primitives, like cubes cylinders etc. If you want to instantiate your prefab at runtime, I suggest you go look at [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html).

You can do this instead:

```
GameObject yourGameObject=whatever;
private void createObject()
{
    caps = Instantiate(yourGameObject);
    Capsules.Enqueue(caps);
}
```

Comment: i did not understood, please will you describe more

Comment: It uses your code above, except instead of caps being the return value from CreatePrimitive(), instead it is the new human GameObject that you just created with the Instantiate method. Then you add caps to the Queue capsule, just like your code above.

Comment: error showing **Cannot implicitly convert type `UnityEngine.GameObject' to `System.Collections.Generic.Queue<UnityEngine.GameObject>**

Comment: how to add **prefabs** as** gameObject** in **queue**

Comment: Try making a public variable and name it myModel. In the Unity UI, go to whatever gameobject you put your script on. Then drag and drop your model into the slot that says My Model(or something else if you named it differently). Then Instantiate myModel.

Comment: You probably are assigning the GameObject to Capsules. Try Capsules.Enqueue instead.